# SSL added to website correctly but says insecure for admin panel

Tags: ssl, craftcms

I have 2 websites one in craft cms 2 and the other in craft cms 3.

Everything works fine except the control panel always shows HTTPS insecure, for both the sites.

Below is my .htacces file,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.co.in
  RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.co.in/$1 [R=301,L]

  # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://www.domain.co.in
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
```

General.php

```
 define('URI_SCHEME',  ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) ? "https://" : "http://" );
    define('SITE_URL',    URI_SCHEME . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/');
    define('BASEPATH',    realpath(CRAFT_BASE_PATH . '/../') . '/');
    return array(
        '*' => array(
            'environmentVariables' => array(
                'siteUrl'  => SITE_URL,
                'basePath' => BASEPATH
            ),
            'cpTrigger' => 'manage',
            'omitScriptNameInUrls' => TRUE, 
            'defaultTokenDuration' => 'P1W',  
            'sendPoweredByHeader' => FALSE, 
            'enableCsrfProtection' => TRUE, 
            'pageTrigger' => 'page/', 
        ),
        'prod' => array(
            'allowAutoUpdates' => FALSE, 
            'env' => 'prod',
            'siteUrl' => 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
        ),
        'stage' => array(    
            'devMode' => FALSE,
            'env' => 'stage',
            'siteUrl' => 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
        ),
        'local' => array(
            'siteUrl' => 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
            'devMode' => TRUE,
            'env' => 'local'
        )
    );
```

Comment: Are you sure that all assets are also loaded in through SSL? (CSS/scripts/images/...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others with the same issue, I managed to get this resolved by adding baseCpUrl in the general.php file

> 'baseCpUrl' => 'https://www.domain.co.in'

For more details visit https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#basecpurl